# incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct protein' from type 'int'

Tags: c

I've been working on this section of my program for awhile but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this last bit.

For the line "protein_powders[largest] = temp;" I'm getting the following error:incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct protein' from type 'int'

How do i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```
 void selection_sort(struct protein protein_powders[], int n)
 {
   struct protein temp;
   int i, largest = 0, temp;  
   if (n == 1)  
   return;

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{   
if (protein_powders[i].averageReview < 
 protein_powders[largest].averageReview)   
       largest = i;  
   if (largest < n - 1) 
  {temp = protein_powders[n-1];}

protein_powders[n-1] = protein_powders[largest];  
protein_powders[largest] = temp;   

selection_sort(protein_powders, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: There are two `temp` declared in your code ? Remove the `int temp` keep only `struct protein temp;`

Comment: how you defined the structure  ?

Answer (score 1):

Which language and which compile are you using. There are several doubts about your code. first of all duplicate declaration of same variable temp. It should throw compile error, something like `error: conflicting declaration ‘protein temp’` . 
 just choose different name and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have `struct protein temp;` and `int temp;` in your code which will cause all sorts of confusion (for you and the compiler).

Looks like you only need the struct version. If you do need both rename the int version to `temp_index` or similar.

Compiling with all warnings enabled would probably highlight this as a problem.